# Output of function in Swift (integer array)

Tags: arrays, function, swift, indexing

```
func calculateStatistics(scores:[Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int, sum: Int)
{
    var max = scores[0]
    var min = scores[0]
    var sum = 0

    for score in scores
    {
        if score > max {
            max = score
        }

        else if score < min {
            min = score
        }

        sum += score
    }

    return (min, max, sum)
}

let numbers = calculateStatistics([5, 3, 100, 3, 9])
numbers
```

Output for `numbers` is `(.0 3, .1 100, .2 120)`. I was wondering if someone could explain the decimal places to me? It looks like indices of the array, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are indexes into the tuple. You can access the first value of the tuple as `numbers.0`, the second as `numbers.1`, and the third as `numbers.2`

Of course you can still use the individual names instead: `numbers.min`, `numbers.max`, `numbers.sum`.

You can also retrieve just certain parts of it by using the `_` placeholder:

```
let (min, max, _) = calculateStatistics([5, 3, 100, 3, 9])
```